# delete button not functioning

Tags: php, mysql

I'm learning PHP with SQL statments, but I've encountered a problem when trying to create a delete button.

The problem is that nothing is happening when i'm pressing the "delete" button.
The query is functioning properly, it gets the correct userid from the loop.

```
<?php
        require_once 'db_connect.php';

        $select = "SELECT * FROM Users";
        $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $select) or die('could not query database');


        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

            echo '
            <tr>
                <td>' . $row['userid'] . '</td>
                <td>' . $row['fnamn'] . ' ' . $row['enamn'] . '</td>
                <td>' . $row['username'] . '</td>
                <td>' . $row['email'] . '</td>
                    <td>' . '<form action="" method="post">
                            <input type="button" name="delete" value="Radera" />
                        </form>' . '</td>

            </tr>';

            if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {

                $userid = $row['userid'];

                $delete = "DELETE FROM Users WHERE userid = '$userid' ";
                $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $delete) or die('could not query database');
            }
        }

        mysqli_close($dbc);
        ?>
```

Comment: You have to use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php). For security reasons injecting a variable in your query (like you are trying now) is not allowed.

Comment: It's ok. I'm just learning, it's not a script that I will actually use in any real enviroments. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: If you are learning, you'd better learn to do it the right way from scratch. Please have a look a prepared statements when you have time. Good luck!

Comment: certainly. But it's overkill to work with it for the assignment I have atm. I will use prepared statements when I do any live projects :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to:

1. Place your `if (isset($_POST['delete']))` statement outside and
   before your `while` loop.
2. Have some way of knowing which row your deleting (maybe with a
   hidden input).

Something like this:

```
<?php
require_once 'db_connect.php';

if(isset($_POST['delete']) && isset($_POST['user_id'])) {
    $userid = $_POST['user_id'];

    $delete = "DELETE FROM Users WHERE userid = '$userid' ";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $delete) or die('could not query database');
}

$select = "SELECT * FROM Users";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $select) or die('could not query database');

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo '
    <tr>
        <td>' . $row['userid'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $row['fnamn'] . ' ' . $row['enamn'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $row['username'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $row['email'] . '</td>
        <td>' . '<form action="" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="user_id" id="user_id" value="'.$row['userid'].'" />
            <input type="submit" name="delete" id="delete" value="Radera" />
        </form>' . '</td>
    </tr>';
}

mysqli_close($dbc);
?>
```

I wouldn't advise you to just insert `$_POST['user_id']` directly into your query like above; you'll want to read up on prepared statements

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I thought that if I used the delete function inside the loop, it would delete only that row. But I see now why that logic would not work.

I will use prepared statments for my live projects, this is just a training excersie for database handelinng through PHP, it's not an actuall user database.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the type.

Instead of:

```
<input type="button" name="delete" value="Radera" />
```

try:

```
<input type="submit" name="delete" value="Radera" />
```

Comment: Totally missed that.
Altho, I tried it, now it deletes all entries if I press delete... I guesds I've made a misstake in the loop.

Comment: @FredrikSkägglösWesterlund, you have to pass which user to delete in your delete form (with `<input type="hidden" name="userid" value="...">` and then use `$_POST['userid']` instead of `$row['userid']`. Also please have a look at prepared statements, cause this code is open to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.